# What type of power supply is best for low resistance experiments?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, short-circuit

I do a lot of experiments with resistive elements/heating elements, electroplating research work and similarly many other experiments. I'm currently using batteries, batteries work well for some time, but it eventually runs out of life, I can't keep changing them as they are expensive, SMPS type power supplies keep shorting for my experiments, even with a simple heating element, it shorts and doesn't work.

Please suggest to me some effective methods or is there any other power supply system that could help me? If you have a solution, please describe it to me.

Comment: You haven't told us what the required voltages or currents are for your experiments, but probably the smartest thing to do is to acquire a "lab" (laboratory) type power supply with an adjustable voltage and current limit. These usually come with short circuit protection. Power supplies don't "short"; loads do if they exceed the supply's maximum current.

Answer (score 2):

There are a wide range of "bench" power supplies, used for developing electrical and electronic products.  A basic one might have an adjustable output voltage, perhaps 0 to 30V, and an adjustable current limit with a maximum of 1 or 2A.  Bigger ones will have higher current limits.

The built-in current limiter makes this type of power supply very robust for a wide variety of experiments.

Most have a built-in voltmeter and ammeter for added convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *constant-current* power supply.  These give constant current at a variable voltage.  But the most useful aspect of them is they are inherently current limited - they cannot give more current than spec. So you aren't going to have *problems* with a dead short, which by the way can explode any battery and throw chemicals everywhere.

In fact, with the early (and very dangerous) transformer-based constant current supplies, placing a dead short on them *is a Code requirement to render them safe!*  (they would make exactly X amps at any voltage; if shorted that was 0 volts). However if given an open circuit, *then voltage would go clear up to infinity* and you got the kind of blood-and-gore casualties like we're seeing today with "fractal wood burning".  So forget a transformer-based CC supply.  Let's talk about modern types.

First, is **LED drivers**. Many of these have a specific current output, typically 0.35 to 1.4 amps, and a variable voltage output within a working range.   They're not strictly made for shorting their outputs, so I would put a high wattage low value resistor in series with them so you don't make magic smoke.

The second and nearly ideal kind of *inherently current-limited* source is **solar panels**.  They have a working target voltage (e.g. in "12V" panels around 13-15 volts), an "open circuit" voltage V<sub>oc</sub> (e.g. around 19 volts), and a "short circuit" voltage V<sub>sc</sub> (e.g. of 10-11 volts) at which the panel will make a limited current I<sub>sc</sub>, which is [part of its specification](https://www.altestore.com/blog/2016/04/how-do-i-read-specifications-of-my-solar-panel/). Like a transformer supply it is routine to short out solar panel outputs during maintenance or testing. [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oaq2cvoPBRk) you see solar being used as a current-limited source to test a breaker; there's nothing wrong with the dead short since the source is solar.

If you want higher working voltages, use more panels in series or larger panels. If you want more current, parallel panels.  This isn't exactly a *regulated* output, you'd still need to measure voltage and current to see what is going on, but it is an extremely robust source that you can use and abuse all day long. (not all night, obviously).  And often, very cheap if you keep an eye on Craigslist.